# Unique path in a connected graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

An undirected connected graph with $n - 1$ edges has only one unique path between any 2 vertices. Is this true. If so, how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This graph is a tree and so it does not contain a cycle. So if there are two points $A,B$ with two paths between them $$P_1 : A\to ...\to B$$ and $$P_2 : A\to ...\to B$$ then path $P_2^{-1}\circ P_1$ would be a cycle wich starts and ends with $A$.

Comment: Technically the walk you give is not a cycle, as vertices may be repeated. It must contain a cycle however.