# connected Graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges contains unique $u-v$ path

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $G$ be a graph with $n\geq 1$ vertices and $m$ edges.
Prove: 
$G$ is connected and $m=n-1 \implies$ $G$ contains a unique $u-v$ path for every $u,v\in G$.
How can i prove this? It is clear that there exists at least 1 path, but how can I show that there exists only one path? I think induction is a good idea.

Comment: Can you prove that your graph contains no cycles, ie is a tree, and then use this uniqueness properties for a tree

Comment: I am not allowed to show that $G$ is acyclic and a tree. I can only use that $G$ is connected and has $n-1$ edges

Comment: @marc it's necessary to show that it's acyclic because otherwise there would be more than one path between two points. Since trees are defined to be acyclic connected graphs this will also be necessary. In fact, you can prove this is a necessary and sufficient set of conditions for a graph to be a tree. I would encourage you to try doing the other implication as well.

Comment: I think the answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042619/unique-path-in-a-connected-graph?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on David's suggestion in the comments: you should show that the given conditions imply that your graph *must* be a tree (there are many ways to do this, but a visually appealing approach would be to induct on the number of vertices). Once you have done this, you can argue by contradiction: if you have two distinct paths between vertices $u$ and $v$, then putting them together there will have to be a cycle somewhere in the graph.